# MySQL how would I handle this type of point system?

Tags: mysql

```
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| NAME    | TITLE             | SIZE | RANK |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
| B       | Snail             | H    |  1   |
| B       | Snail             | M    |  1   |
| B       | Snail             | L    |  1   |
| C       | Dog               | H    |  1   |
| C       | Dog               | M    |  1   |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
```

Example of exact data pulled from above

```
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | M    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
| A       | Hippo             | H    |  1   |
| A       | Hippo             | H    | N/A  |
+---------+-------------------+------+------+
```

Points are as follows:

```
H = 70 points
M = 20 points
L = 10 points
```

- Hippo has 4 `H` in size column.
- `H` in total can equal 70.
- Therefore 70/4 = 17.5
- This means each single `H` can only have 17.5 points.
- Points are aquired if 'Rank' is present.
- Hippo has only two 'Rank' present.
- Therefore Hippo gains (17.5)x(2)=35 points.
- Hippo also has an `M` present in 'size' column.
- Therefore `M` = 20/1 =20.
- Therefore hippo gains 20 points.
- Hippo has no `L` in size column.
- Therefore no points gained.
- Which totals 35 (from `H`) + 20 (from `M`) + 0 (from `L`) = 55.

Desired output

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| NAME    | TITLE    | SCORE |
+---------+----------+-------+
| A       | Hippo    |   55  |
| B       | Snail    |  100  |
| C       | Dog      |   90  |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

How do you do this type of complex scoring/variable handling in MySQl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a complex sub select and joins, here is the result you are expecting:

```
select c.name,c.title,sum(score) from (
select b.name, b.title, avg_point*needcount as score from (select name, title, size,    count(size),  (case when size='H' then 70 when size='M' then 20 when size='L' then 10 end )/ count(size)  as avg_point from points group by name,title,size ) a
join 
(select name, title, size, count(size) as needcount from points where rank group by name, title, size) b
on a.name = b.name
and a.title = b.title
and a.size = b.size) c group by c.name,c.title;
```